# Appending concrete values to array of interfaces

Tags: go

I have the following structures:

```
type Type interface {
  getFoo() []byte
}

type Concrete struct {
}

func (this *Concrete) getFoo() []byte {
   example := []byte{2, 3, 4}
   return example
}
```

Now I have some array of `Type` interfaces, e.g.:

`var arr []*Type`

And I want to create array of concrete structures and initialize the above array with it, e.g.:

```
var cObjArr []*Concrete
cObj := new(Concrete)
cObjArr = append(cObjArr, cObj)
arr = cObj
```

But it gives me an error that `cannot use type []*Concrete as type []*Type in assignment`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

First,

```
type Type interface{} {
  getFoo() []byte
}
```

should be

```
type Type interface {
  getFoo() []byte
}
```

I assume that is a result of trying to show a small, reproducible example.

The next is that `arr` should be a slice of type `Type`, not `*Type`.  A pointer to an interface is VERY rarely what you actually mean.

So, your `arr` is now a slice of `Type`... `[]Type`.  For the remainder of the current scope `arr` will always HAVE TO BE of type `[]Type`.

`cObjArr` is of type `[]*Concrete`.  That's fine, but the value of `cObjArr` can not be assigned to `arr` since it is a different type.

You have a couple options here.

1. Instead of appending to `cObjArr`, just append to `arr`

https://play.golang.org/p/m3-83s6R5c

2. Or iterate through `cObjArr` and append to `arr`

https://play.golang.org/p/wvWaChcOWY

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should declare `arr` as `[]Type` instead of `[]*Type`. The objects you want to put in the array are `Type`, not `*Type` (`*Concrete` implements the `Type` interface).

Based on the error, your code must be trying to do `arr = cObjArr`. You can't do that because the types of the two slice objects are different. Instead, you can append `cObj` directly to `arr`.